# Good practice to place Modal code in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a site, but have come across a stumbling block.  I am trying to follow proper MVC design pattern.

Will it be good practice to place the modal html inside the "Index" view that is responsible for displaying all people?  For instance, I have a table listing all people.  Each person entry in the table has a "View/Edit" button, and when I click on that, I want to display the modal.  Can this modal code reside inside the "Index" view, and be triggered by the "View/Edit" button, or should I call the appropriate action in the controller to somehow return the Modal?

Here is my code currently if you need to see what I have done so far. Below the modal code is residing in the "Index" view.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Date Of Birth", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DOBSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Last Reg Date", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LARDSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Last Reg Number", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LARNSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Reg Count", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RegCountSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Gender", "PersonList", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GenderSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="updatedContent">
                @foreach (var person in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@person.Name  @person.Surname</td>
                        <td>@person.BirthDate</td>
                        <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationDate_Description</td>
                        <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationNo_Description</td>
                        <td>@person.ActiveRegistrationCount_Description</td>
                        <td>@person.Gender_Description</td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("View/Edit", "", "", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-md", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal" })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("PersonList",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

@* Modal code here for editing the Person *@
@* Called upon the Click of Edit/View *@
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">View/Edit Person</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Here we will be able to View/Edit the Person object.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use it there, i'm not expert in c# but will you be aple to populate the form with the selected person to edit ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why you wouldn't put the markup for that view *in that view*.  Putting it in a separate view and dynamically invoking it may have benefits in some situations, but I don't think this is one of them.

Usually you'd do that if the "modal" component needs to fetch more data.  Because in that case it's a trade-off between fetching small amounts of data in multiple HTTP requests vs. putting *all* of the data on the page in the initial request.  If it's likely that users will interact with only a small number of records, you wouldn't want to put all of the data there.

If, however, all of the data needed is already on the page anyway then there's really no reason to put this markup in a separate HTTP request.  Because then you'd be repeating that request to get *the same markup* every time someone edits a record.  Might as well just send it once when the page loads.

If there's a lot of data which differs per record, consider using AJAX requests.  If it's just a hidden edit form in the markup, keep it in the same markup.  The fact that it's "modal" is a UI concern, not a separate request concern.